# Amsterdam transit with Turkish passport

Tags: visas, transit, transit-visas, ams, turkish-citizens

I am flying to US with a transit in Amsterdam for 15 hours. I have a Turkish passport and f1 visa for US. Do I need a visa for transit in Amsterdam?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&page=visa&NA=TR&AR=00&PASSTYPES=PASS&selDest=Use%20ctrl-key%20to%20select%20or%20deselect%20destination%28s%29%20above&TR=NL&selTrans=Netherlands&user=PEARL&subuser=PEARL), the database used by Airlines:

> Visa required, **except** for Holders of onward tickets transiting by the same or first connecting aircraft.

So if the trip is in one booking, you do **not** Need a visa

More info on transiting Schengen can be found [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30569/do-i-need-a-visa-to-transit-or-layover-in-the-schengen-area)

Comment: This is covered in the canonical, please be sure to add a link so that the OP can get a comprehensive answer, thanks.